# Swapping dictionary keys and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Here is a MWE of my problem.

I have a dictionary with the keys 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'. Each dictionary value is a dataframe with the same columns '1', '2', '3', '4'.

I wish to change the data format to be a dictionary with keys '1', '2', '3', '4'. With dataframes inside containing columns 'A' 'B', 'C', 'D'.

The data in column '1' of dictionary 'A' will end up in column 'A' o dictionary '1'.

Here is the code to construct the initial dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
dict_num ={}
for i in range(1,5): 
    dict_num[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Here is the code for the conversion:

```
def convert_dictionary(dict_num): 
    col_num = list(dict_num.values())[0].columns # Extract the column names of first dictionary (columns in all df are identical)
    alpha_df = pd.DataFrame() #Create empty dataframe 
    dict_alpha = {key: alpha_df for key in col_num} #Create new dictionary with columns as keys and the empty dictionary as keys 
    for df in dict_num: #Iterate through the initial dictionary
        for column in dict_num[df]:  #Iterate through the initial columns
            dict_alpha[column].insert(len(dict_alpha[column].columns), df, dict_num[df][column])# Insert the column into the new dictionary with column and key switched 
    return dict_alpha

dict_alpha = convert_dictionary(dict_num)
```

The first column goes in correctly column '1' in dict_alpha['A']. The next column should enter into the next new dictionary dict_alpha['B'] as column '1'. However, I get a ValueError. I assume the output is copying into all dictionaries but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating `dict_alpha` in the function, you refer to the same empty dataframe `alpha_df` hence same memory space, replace it by

```
dict_alpha = {key: pd.DataFrame() for key in col_num}
```

and no need to define `alpha_df` anymore.

You can also to the operation with `concat` and `groupby`:

```
dict_alpha = {key : val.droplevel(axis=1,level=1) 
              for key, val in pd.concat(dict_num, axis=1).groupby(level=1, axis=1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if this is the solution your are looking for.

```
def convert_dictionary(dict_num): 
    col_num = list(dict_num.values())[0].columns
    alpha_df = pd.DataFrame() #Create empty dataframe 
    dict_alpha = {}
    for k,v in dict_num.items(): #Iterate through the initial dictionary
        for column in v.columns:
            df=pd.DataFrame({k:v[column]})
            dict_alpha.update({column:pd.concat([dict_alpha.get(column),df],axis=1)})
    return dict_alpha
```